# Pandas For Loop Copy/Paste and Export to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, for-loop

I have a CSV file that has the following data:

| Product | Date | Company | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2/1/2021 | 1230 | 24314 |
| A | 2/1/2021 | 1224 | 14222 |
| B | 2/1/2021 | 1442 | 24141 |
| B | 2/1/2021 | 1424 | 54352 |
| B | 2/1/2021 | 4919 | 12213 |
| C | 2/1/2021 | 2312 | 43536 |
| C | 2/1/2021 | 2322 | 24241 |
| D | 2/1/2021 | 1131 | 34532 |
| E | 2/1/2021 | 1414 | 45645 |
| E | 2/1/2021 | 7674 | 21321 |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

I need to filter on the Product column for each product and copy/paste the filtered results to its own separate CSV—is there a way to do this with a for loop? In other words, I need a CSV for each product that’s filtered. This is currently what I have for Product A:

```
report_import = (r’path\product_report.csv")

report_df = pd.read_csv(report_import, sep='\t',encoding="utf16")

report_df = report_df[report_df[‘Product’] == 'A']

report_df.to_csv(r"path\ProductA.csv", index=False)
```

And basically I'd like to rinse and repeat but for the other products

Comment: How did you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter like this

```py
report_import = (r’path\product_report.csv")

report_df = pd.read_csv(report_import, sep='\t',encoding="utf16")

# Get all available products
products = set(report_df[‘Product’])

for product in products:
    #Perform a filter for each product
    temp_df = report_df[report_df[‘Product’] == product]
    temp_df.to_csv(r"path\" + product + ".csv", index=False)
```

Saving to csv files based on the product.